# Android: How can I port ExecuteScalar to Java?

Tags: c#, java, android, sqlite, sql-server-express

> **SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method**
>   Executes the query, and returns
>   the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the
>   query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

I guess this will involve heavy use of generics.

Assume I have an [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)/[Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic worked for me:

```
public int ExecuteScalar(/* code...*/) {
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
    try {
        cursor.moveToNext();
        int val = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
        return val;
    }   
    catch (Exception e) {
        /* code...*/
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [SQLLiteStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html)

> `long     simpleQueryForLong()` Execute a statement that returns a 1 by 1
>   table with a numeric value.
>
> `String   simpleQueryForString()` Execute a statement that returns a 1 by 1 table with a text value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're retrieving a primary key then you can use the statement getGeneratedKeys method which returns a resultSet of generated keys after an insert.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the database object is `db`

```
long result = db.compileStatement("select count(*) from some_table").simpleQueryForLong();
```