# How to return Count value from android SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

What i have is a table called MASTER and i have insert and viewed the data correctly , but now i want to count the CUSTOMER field in the table , here is my method in the class :

```
  public int Count() {

            String sql="SELECT COUNT (CUSTOMER) as 'customerCount' FROM MASTER";
             Cursor c=database.rawQuery(sql, null);
            return 0;

        }
```

What shall i add to this code so i can store count value in an int variable?? please help i am new at sqlite...

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7552122/72746

Comment: use int count=c.getInt(0);

Comment: There is also a helper method `longForQuery` in `DatabaseUtils` - utility method to run the query on the db and return the value in the first column of the first row.

Comment: @sereen -1 returns in the case of exception, so you can handle it in calling code. It's just error code. There is another variant, e.g. you can use exceptions: http://damienkatz.net/2006/04/error_code_vs_e.html

Comment: @Axarydax can you make your comment as an answer so i can vote it?